# Reference TextBlock element in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, datatemplate

I have a Data Template in my XAML page with data binding. This Data Template resides directly on the XAML page, it is not referenced by another structure such as a GridView or ListView.  It is not used as an ItemTemplate.

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="Standard250x480ItemTemplate">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250" Height="480" Margin="0 0 0 0">
            <!--<Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">-->
            <Border Background="#ffffff">
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="Uniform" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}" />
            </Border>

            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                <TextBlock x:Name="Title" TextAlignment="Center"  Padding="0 18 0 0" FontSize="25" Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0" />
                <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10"/>-->
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

    </DataTemplate>
```

This works fine. But when trying to call or reference an element in the Data Template from the cs code behind the XAML page, it gets an error.

When I try:

```
public click()
{
  var title=Title.Text;
}
```

The TextBlock is not recognized. I have used this before and it worked fine, but not in a Data Template.

I want to use whatever the value of the `Text` property in the TextBlock named "Title" in the click function so that I can pass it to another page in the app. For this I need to get the Text value of the TextBlock.

What am I doing wrong? How do I work with elements in a Data Template?

Comment: Can you share some more details about what you like to achieve?

Comment: I made some edits above. Does this help?

Comment: I don't get why you are using a DataTemplate if this is not used in any iterating Controls such as gridview, listview etc. If I understand you right, it would probably be better to make this a UserControl, but I might be misinterpreting Your question.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Title is included in a DataTemplate, it is not possible to refer it from code behind. What if you're including this template in a ListBox; there could be several Title TextBlocks

In order to find your DataTemplate from code-behind you can use this:

```
this.TryFindResource("Standard250x480ItemTemplate");
```

Then you must cast it to DataTemplate, then you would have to use VisualTreeHelper or LogicalTreeHelper to find the TextBlock.

The best solution is to use your ViewModel object (I see you're using Text="{Binding Title}"). Getting the Item from your ListBox or Content from i.e your ContentControl, you could cast it into your ViewModel instance like this:

```
var viewModel = (MyViewModel)listBox.SelectedItem;
var title = viewModel.Title;
```

Comment: you don't need to use c# to create the binding (no cast necessary).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the name of Title since it's used by the presentation form itself

To avoid this in the future use:

TextBoxTitle or something simular